# Что нужно знать для передачи и получения данных в сети на c#?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Есть сервер(сайт ThingWorx) 
Протокол HTTP 1.1
Он принимает данные в json. Что нужно почитать и посмотреть, чтобы написать отправку и приём json данных, зная адрес, на c#?

Comment: Ну, вроде, поправил

Comment: [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) и библиотека JSON.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете попробовать просто отправлять `JSON` в строковом формате при помощи `HttpClient`. Для более гибкого формирования самих json-объектов, используйте любую из библиотек .NET, работающих с `JSON`. Их полно на [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org):

```
var json = "{ 'field1': 'value1', 'field2': 'value2' }";
var apiUrl = "https://www.thingworx.com/pathtoapi";
HttpResponseMessage response = null;
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.PostAsync(apiUrl, new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
    .ContinueWith(t => response = t.Result);
```

Comment: `ContinueWith`? А почему не async/await?

Comment: Мне показалось,  что для примера так будет проще.